# How to check customer purchase movement

Tags: sql, oracle, data-analysis

> I want to monitor the purchasing behavior of customers. Each customer can purchase one or more products, with different price ranges for each product. How can I determine if a customer is buying consistently, switching to a smaller bundle, or upgrading to a larger bundle?

As of now, I have the below SQL script to see the movement, but how can I modify this to make it advance and get more details that I need?

```
SELECT 
A.Month PRE_MONTH,A.ProductID PRE_PRODUCTID,
A.Product_name PRE_PRODUCT_NAME,
B.Month POST_MONTH,B.ProductID POST_PRODUCTID,
B.Product_name POST_PRODUCT_NAME,
SUM(B.sales)sales, COUNT(DISTINCT B.CustomerID)USER
FROM ( SELECT * FROM TABLE_X WHERE MONTH = 'JAN' ) A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ( SELECT * FROM TABLE_X WHERE MONTH = 'FEB')B ON A.CustomerID = B.CustomerID
```

What adjustments should be made to the SQL script to identify if customer 1 has generated higher or lower sales compared to the previous month? Additionally, how can we determine which products they have transitioned from and to?

The raw data will look like this:

[image]

Comment: In addition to replacing images with sample data formatted as text, you should also include your desired output (again, not as a picture). Also, you have two questions here, so you may want to limit to just one question.

Answer (score 0):

You can self join the table with different months and then simply use the case statement to determine whether it is higher or lower sales -

```
SELECT jan_data.CustomerId,
       PRE_PRODUCTID first_product_id,
       PRE_PRODUCT_NAME first_product_name,
       PRE_SALES first_sales,
       POST_PRODUCTID new_product_id,
       POST_PRODUCT_NAME new_product_name,
       POST_SALES new_sales,
       CASE WHEN first_sales > new_sales THEN 'Lower Sales'
            WHEN first_sales < new_sales THEN 'Higher Sales'
            ELSE 'Equal'
       END sales_scale
  FROM (SELECT j.ProductID PRE_PRODUCTID,
               j.Product_name PRE_PRODUCT_NAME,
               j.CustomerId,
               SUM(J.Sales) PRE_SALES
          FROM TABLE_X j WHERE MONTH = 'JAN'
       ) jan_data
  FULL JOIN (SELECT f.month POST_MONTH,
               f.ProductID POST_PRODUCTID,
               f.Product_name POST_PRODUCT_NAME,
               f.CustomerId,
               SUM(J.Sales) POST_SALES
          FROM TABLE_X f WHERE MONTH = 'FEB'
       ) feb_data ON jan_data.CustomerId = feb_data.CustomerId
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the options is to use [LAG() analytic function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions082.htm#SQLRF00652) to compare the sales with previous ones.

```sql
WITH    --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
    tbl ( A_MONTH, CUSTOMER_ID, PRODUCT_ID, PRODUCT_NAME, SALES ) AS
        (   Select '2023-01', 1, 444, 'aaa', 40 From Dual Union All
            Select '2023-01', 2, 333, 'bbb', 30 From Dual Union All
            Select '2023-01', 3, 222, 'ccc', 20 From Dual Union All
            Select '2023-01', 4, 444, 'aaa', 40 From Dual Union All
            Select '2023-01', 5, 1111, 'ddd', 10 From Dual Union All    
            --
            Select '2023-02', 1, 333, 'bbb', 30 From Dual Union All
            Select '2023-02', 2, 444, 'aaa', 40 From Dual Union All
            Select '2023-02', 3, 222, 'ccc', 20 From Dual Union All
            Select '2023-02', 4, 1111, 'ddd', 10 From Dual Union All
            Select '2023-02', 5, 333, 'bbb', 30 From Dual Union All
            --
            Select '2023-03', 1, 444, 'aaa', 40 From Dual Union All
            Select '2023-03', 2, 333, 'bbb', 30 From Dual Union All
            Select '2023-03', 3, 222, 'ccc', 20 From Dual Union All
            Select '2023-03', 4, 444, 'aaa', 40 From Dual Union All
            Select '2023-03', 5, 1111, 'ddd', 10 From Dual 
        )
```

Main SQL

```sql
Select  A_MONTH, CUSTOMER_ID, SALES,
        LAG(SALES) Over(Partition By CUSTOMER_ID Order By CUSTOMER_ID, A_MONTH) "PREV_MONTH_SALES",
        Case  When LAG(SALES) Over(Partition By CUSTOMER_ID Order By CUSTOMER_ID, A_MONTH) > SALES
              Then 'DOWN'
              When LAG(SALES) Over(Partition By CUSTOMER_ID Order By CUSTOMER_ID, A_MONTH) < SALES
              Then 'UP'
              When LAG(SALES) Over(Partition By CUSTOMER_ID Order By CUSTOMER_ID, A_MONTH) = SALES
              Then 'SAME'
        End "MOVEMENT"
From      tbl
Order By CUSTOMER_ID, A_MONTH
--  
--    R e s u l t :
--  A_MONTH CUSTOMER_ID      SALES PREV_MONTH_SALES MOVE
--  ------- ----------- ---------- ---------------- ----
--  2023-01           1         40                      
--  2023-02           1         30               40 DOWN
--  2023-03           1         40               30 UP  
--  2023-01           2         30                      
--  2023-02           2         40               30 UP  
--  2023-03           2         30               40 DOWN
--  2023-01           3         20                      
--  2023-02           3         20               20 SAME
--  2023-03           3         20               20 SAME
--  2023-01           4         40                      
--  2023-02           4         10               40 DOWN
--  2023-03           4         40               10 UP  
--  2023-01           5         10                      
--  2023-02           5         30               10 UP  
--  2023-03           5         10               30 DOWN
```

LAG() Analytic function could get you the products movement too. Just add another column to the selection list:

```sql
Nvl(LAG(PRODUCT_NAME) Over(Partition By CUSTOMER_ID Order By CUSTOMER_ID, A_MONTH), 'n/a') || ' --> ' || PRODUCT_NAME "PRODUCT_MOVE"
-- Result fror CUSTOMER_ID = 1
--  A_MONTH CUSTOMER_ID      SALES PREV_MONTH_SALES MOVE PRODUCT_MOVE
--  ------- ----------- ---------- ---------------- ---- ------------
--  2023-01           1         40                       n/a --> aaa
--  2023-02           1         30               40 DOWN aaa --> bbb
--  2023-03           1         40               30 UP   bbb --> aaa
```

If the original data should be summed first then you could create CTE (named it sales) and select from CTE instead of tbl. You should take care of product movement column if it is in selection list - if not the below code could be used:

```sql
  sales AS
    ( Select A_MONTH, CUSTOMER_ID, Sum(SALES) "SALES"
      From   tbl
      Group By  A_MONTH, CUSTOMER_ID
    )
```